# Adding watermarks to images using alpha channels in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, watermark

I find the code below on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php) and it is working perfectly when i add the images mentioned in code (`$stamp & $im`)

```
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stamp.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');
```

but my question is that how to use or implement this code in Wordpress post image fetched using

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID )
```

also some one please explain me what is happening here. where to add this code? how to make all wordpress post images watermarked with this code.

```
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stamp.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use in below hook:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_filter' );
function custom_upload_filter( $file ){
    //your code goes here.
    return $file;
}
```

Reference
[Hook into Wordpress image upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580429/hook-into-wordpress-image-upload)

Comment: I tried this but it goes into infinite loop and the link you mentioned is for change image size while upload but i want this in post list and in single post featured image